# Listening to specific port in C# sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, port

I'm have problem with listening to specified port. I have the following code:

```
Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Unspecified);
Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localAddr, 80));

Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
Socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, BitConverter.GetBytes(1), BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

Socket.BeginReceive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), null);
```

and everything seems to work just fine, i capture incoming and outgoing packets, I have all the information I need with just one exception - it listens to all ports, not only 80 as I specified in Bind() method. Does anyone have any ideas how can I read just these on port 80?

Comment: What makes you think that it listens to *all* ports?

Comment: May be because browser is using that port 80 for HTTP

Comment: Pavel K I know so because I receive packets from applications that use totally different ports than 80 and they are all 'visible' in BeginReceive().

Comment: Anyone? I don't want to filter all packets by checking the port they're coming to and showing only these with 80...

Answer (score 0):

> I have all the information I need with just one exception - it listens to all ports, not only 80 as I specified in Bind() method

There isn't any exception. From the code that you have posted, it is not possible that it is reading from any port other than port 80.

Comment: Well, when I parse the data from packet, I receive something like this:

Source address:10.132.0.0
Dest address: 10.132.186.191
Protocol type: UDP
Is fragmented: False

        Source port: 137
        Dest port: 137
        Acknlg number: 0
        ASCII Data fragment:

it appears that it gets data from other ports as well, and I can trace packets from different applications that use some exotic ports not even remotely connected with HTTP...

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Documentation from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309610(v=vs.85).aspx) tells us that with this line

```
Socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, BitConverter.GetBytes(1), BitConverter.GetBytes(0));
```

the network interface controller will *capture **all** IPv4 or IPv6 traffic on the LAN*. I don't know a way how to limit this to a certain port by configuration, so I think you have to filter the data by yourself.